Reusing overloaded parameter definitions for functions with different returns
I have two functions which have the same overloading of parameters but return different things. Is there someway I can abstract the overloading definition into a shared definition that I can reference from both places.
e.g. I would like to avoid having overload definitions for both addRoute and createRoute
class Router {
    addRoute(url: RouteOptions): void;
    addRoute(url: string, options?: RouteOptions): void;

    createRoute(url: RouteOptions): Route;
    createRoute(url: string, options?: RouteOptions): Route;
}

Is there some way I can define a type something like OverloadedFunctionParameters and then have:
class Router {
    addRoute(OverloadedFunctionParameters): void;
    createRoute(OverloadedFunctionParameters): Route;
}

FYI, the example above is very much simplified compared to my actual use case

Those don't need to be overloads because the return type for each call signature is the same; you can use a union of rest tuples instead. That is, {(...args: X): R; (...args: Y): R} is equivalent to {(...args: X | Y): R}. Hence the answer below is what I'd suggest for the example as given. Does that meet your needs? If not, please [edit] the question to show a case where this suggestion fails.

You could do something like this, using the ... "spread" operator to turn an array type into a set of parameters:
type RouteParams = [url: RouteOptions] | [url: string, options?: RouteOptions];

class Router {
    addRoute(...routeParams: RouteParams): void;
    createRoute(...routeParams: RouteParams): Route;
}


Nice idea - thanks
